# Trying to create and use a class; name 'is_empty' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class called `Stack` (it's probably not very useful for writing actual programmes, I'm just doing it to learn about creating classes in general) and this is my code, identical to the example in the guide I'm following save for one function name:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

I saved it in a file called `stack.py` and tested it with this:

```
from stack import Stack

my_stack = Stack()

print(is_empty(my_stack))
```

but I got this error message:

```
Mac:python mac$ python3 stacktest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stacktest.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(is_empty(my_stack))
NameError: name 'is_empty' is not defined
```

The guide in question has something called activecode, which is basically Python installed on the browser so you can run example programmes on it, and `is_empty(my_stack)` returns `True` like it should. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Yeah, it's actually `my_stack.is_empty()`. I mixed classes up with functions AND misread the guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `is_empty()` is part of the class. To call it you need to `my_stack.is_empty()`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I understand dot notation better now.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is probably

```
from stack import Stack

my_stack = Stack()

print my_stack.is_empty()
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be

my_stack.is_empty()

Answer (score 1):

There is no global name `is_empty` defined. There is, however, an `is_empty` attribute in the class bound to the global name `Stack`. You would need to use either

```
Stack.is_empty(my_stack)
```

or the far more common usage

```
my_stack.is_empty().
```

Comment: `Stack.is_empty()` won't work unless the `@classmethod` decorator is used. Otherwise `is_empty()` is an instance method and requires an instance of the class.

Comment: `is_empty` takes exactly one argument, an instance of the `Stack` class. Whether you supply an instance of the class explicitly, as in my first example, or implicitly, as in the second, does not matter.